# DnD 4E list of poisons

Tags: dnd-4e

Ok, so I've researched it quite thoroughly, and although there are a few venoms, and a few potions that can be used that way (The Goodnight Tincture), aside from those listed in Adventurer's vault and Mordechainen's I haven't found any actual poisons.

I specifically need poisons that can be spread by touch, or ingested through food and water, but if you can point me to a Dragon or another book, I'd be happy to read through all of them.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

The assassin (executioner) class in Heroes of Shadow are given poisons instead of dailies. Carrion crawler brain juice, bloodroot poison, greenblood oil, id moss powder, nitharit poison, ungol dust are all in Heroes of Shadow. I believe there is more but those are what you get as an assassin (executioner) if you need info on more I'll try to find you some.

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot, and I found exactly what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 1):

There are several poisons in the good old DMG, but they are pretty much basic ongoing damage. I think that most of them are translated into Essentials for Heroes of Shadow. Here they are:

From the Dungeon Master's Guide, Page 51:

> Stormclaw Scorpion Venom, Deathjump Spider Poison, Carrion Crawler Brain
>   Juice, Ground Thassil Root, Dark Toxin, Drow Poison, Hellstinger Scorpion
>   Venom, Blood of Zehir, Demonweb Terror Venom, Black Lotus, Insanity Mist,
>   Pit Toxin.